# Inheriting theme from parent Sharepoint 2013 online

Tags: sharepoint-online

i'm working to my diplom project in SharePoint 2013 online and  i need to add a subsite to an shared Platform.
Now i got a problem cause i couldn't inherit the theme from parent, i read around searching, but i only find:" check the 'inherit from parent' under site settings -> look and feel -> master page " 
but i didn't find the master page under look and feel, i searched in all options that i have under look and feel but i didn't found this checkbox.
or i found too .net coding but i have not the permissons to work in server side or with .net

there are other methods to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the Publishing Feature enabled in your new subsite, under 'Manage Site Features' in the Site Actions section of your Site Settings page. Once this feature is enabled, you should see the 'Master Page' option in the Look and Feel section and be able to set it to inherit from the parent.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to first go to parent site and check if you have activate the publishing feature.

Go to parent site settings > Site collection features under Site Collection Administration section.

There is one feature named "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure", click 'Activate' button.

Then go to subsite site settings > Manage site features and activate a feature called "SharePoint Server Publishing".

Then check if you can see the master page option under look and feel in subsite setting.